# Static Web Service over non-static

Tags: static, non-static

Currently I have a web service (WCF) that exposes methods that are set to static.

From a strictly memory/GC perspective, what is different in how the CLR and GC handle static versus non-static objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static data won't be garbage-collected until the containing AppDomain is shut down; commonly this means the memory will stay allocated until the app is shut down, unless you're doing some kind of special AppDomain management.  Non-static objects will be collected by the garbage collector, by the normal rules - no more references, and whenever the GC runs.

Comment: Cool stuff. We are having some excessive memory allocation problems (over 400MB) for an application that is intended to run for weeks at a time. When we couldn't find anything else wrong we thought it might have been related to us using static objects. We will start recoding to non-static starting tomorrow. Thanks for your help!

Comment: John- I disagree when that 400MB takes the entire system down. After modifing the code for non-static we were able to get the application to peak at 18MB which is reasonable. Thanks again Bruce!